# can var_prompt be included in a role?

Tags: ansible

I have written a simple play book master.yml,the main function is to lookup the roles and enter one as input for second playbook. But it doesn't prompt for the variables eventhough I used var_prompt role.

```
--- #master.yml

- name: show roles.
  hosts: nodes
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - include: showroles.yml

- name: createdb and map roles.
  hosts: nodes
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - vars_prompt_role
  tasks:
    - include: createdb.yml
```

My directory structured as following:

```
/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/
[user@localhost createdbandmaprole]$ ls
createdb.yml  hosts  master.yml  roles  script.sql.j2  showroles.yml
[user@localhost createdbandmaprole]$cd roles
[user@localhost roles]$ ls
var_prompt_role
[user@localhost roles]$ cd var_prompt_role/
[user@localhost var_prompt_role]$ ls
defaults  handlers  library  main.yml  meta  tasks  vars
[user@localhost var_prompt_role]$ vim main.yml
vars_prompt:
 - name: "database"
   prompt: "enter the name of database"
   private: no
 - name: "role"
   prompt: "enter the name of role"
   private: no
 - name: "ad_group"
   prompt: "enter the AD_Group"
   private: no
[user@localhost createdbandmaprole]$ ansible-playbook master.yml -i hosts --check
```

but it doesn't prompt for vars

Comment: How does the question in the title relate to the contents?

Answer (score 3):

`vars_prompt` should be called from the top level of the playbook, not a task:

> Here is a most basic example:
>
> ```
> ---
> - hosts: all
>   remote_user: root
>
>   vars:
>     from: "camelot"
>
>   vars_prompt:
>     - name: "name"
>       prompt: "what is your name?"
>     - name: "quest"
>       prompt: "what is your quest?"
>     - name: "favcolor"
>       prompt: "what is your favorite color?"
> ```

So you might actually want to be calling `vars_prompt` as shown above, according to [this page](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_prompts.html).

If you had a role to call `vars_prompt`, it would be defined in its own file under a `roles/` directory, which should live at the same level as your playbook. In your case, it might look like this:

```
--- #master.yml

...
- name: createdb and map roles.
  hosts: nodes
  roles:
      - vars_prompt_role
...
```

Then in `roles/vars_prompt_role/tasks/main.yml`, you would define the `vars_prompt_role` role's tasks. For more information on roles, check out [this page](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_roles.html), or see [this page](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#content-organization) for best practices on content organization.

This is how your `roles/` directory should look:

```
roles/
   var_prompt_role/
     files/
     templates/
     tasks/
       main.yml
     handlers/
     vars/
     defaults/
     meta/
```

Where `main.yml` is the main task you want to carry out for this role.

Comment: Thank you @McGlothlin. I tried your suggestion it prompted for variables but it prompted for variable even before the execution  of first playbook. Is there a method where I can enter the variables after the  excution of  first playbook??

Comment: You referenced the role in the second playbook, correct? Plays run from top to bottom in the order you specify. See here for more info: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example

Comment: @Nanda shoot, I didn't realize `vars_prompt` was a section and not a role (sorry, it's been a while). Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there a syntax where I can define vars_prompt as a role??because I only see defining vars as a role syntax.

Comment: No, I don't think that's necessary... you could either stick a `vars_prompt` in a role of its own, or just call it from your second playbook as demonstrated above. Does that make sense?

Comment: This is the error that occured.
ERROR: found role at /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_role, but cannot find /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_role/tasks/main or /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_role/handlers/main or /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_role/vars/main or /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_role/defaults/main or /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_role/meta/main or /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_role/library

Comment: You have to create the directory structure for the role, even if you're not creating files in some of those folders.

Comment: /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/main
/home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/tasks/main 
/home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/handlers/main 
/home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/vars/main 
/home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/defaults/main 
/home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/meta/main  
/home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/library/main

Comment: where /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/main looks like
vars_prompt:
 - name: "database"
   prompt: "enter the name of database"
   private: no
 - name: "role"
   prompt: "enter the name of role"
   private: no
 - name: "ad_group"
   prompt: "enter the AD_Group"
   private: no

Comment: by using the above dir structure its not prompting for the vars, I even tried
 /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_rol‌​e/vars/main
vars_prompt:
 - name: "database"
   prompt: "enter the name of database"
   private: no
 - name: "role"
   prompt: "enter the name of role"
   private: no
 - name: "ad_group"
   prompt: "enter the AD_Group"
   private: no

Comment: I don't quite follow. Could you please edit the question and include how you have your playbook(s) and role(s) structured on the file system?

Comment: I did include my file structure in the question

Comment: Ah, thanks for the edit. I've updated my answer to match.

Comment: ERROR: expecting dict; got: vars_prompt, error in /home/USER/playbooks/createdbandmaprole/roles/var_prompt_role/tasks/main.yml