# Would it be possible to create a playbook with Ansible that would prompt before running every role?

Tags: ansible

I have collection of roles and hosts that these roles are run against. But I also have "custom" hosts that only need some of those roles, and it varies which roles which host needs. How could I create a playbook which would run against specific group of hosts and ask before  every role whether the role should be run?

So far I created playbook custom.yml (which doesn't work...):

```
- name: Select roles
  hosts: custom
  become: yes
  roles:
  - role: custom
  - { role: common, when: run_common == "Y" or run_common == "y" }
  - { role: system, when: run_system == "Y" or run_system == "y" }
  - { role: date, when: run_date == "Y" or run_date == "y" }
  - { role: swap, when: run_swap == "Y" or run_swap == "y" }
  - { role: users, when: run_users == "Y" or run_users == "y" }
```

I created a role to prompt whether to run a specific role or not - custom/tasks/main.yml:

```
- include_tasks: select_roles.yml
  with_items:
  - common
  - system
  - date
  - swap
  - users
```

custom/tasks/select_roles.yml:

```
- include_vars:
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "run_{{ item }}"
      prompt: "Run {{ item }}?"
      default: "N"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        run_{{ item }}: "run_{{ item }}"
      when: "run_{{ item }}" == "Y"
```

At the moment I have it running all inside a single playbook but it's lot of copy-paste and editing, and looks ugly:

```
- name: Run select roles on all custom nodes
  hosts: custom
  become: yes
  vars_prompt:
     - name: "run_common"
     prompt: "Run common?"
     default: "N"
     private: no
     - name: "run_system"
     prompt: "Run system?"
     default: "N"
     private: no
     - name: "run_date"
     prompt: "Run date?"
     default: "N"
     private: no
     - name: "run_swap"
     prompt: "Run swap?"
     default: "N"
     private: no
     - name: "run_users"
     prompt: "Run users?"
     default: "N"
     private: no
  roles:
  - { role: common, when: run_common == "Y" or run_common == "y" }
  - { role: system, when: run_system == "Y" or run_system == "y" }
  - { role: date, when: run_date == "Y" or run_date == "y" }
  - { role: swap, when: run_swap == "Y" or run_swap == "y" }
  - { role: users, when: run_users == "Y" or run_users == "y" }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can var\_prompt be included in a role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201169/can-var-prompt-be-included-in-a-role)

Comment: @imjoseangel Thanks for pointing to it. It's somewhat similar but not quite the same as I'm trying to use variables ("run_{{ item }}") and loops (with_items) to create dynamic vars_prompt.

Comment: Another question. So every time you want to run a role against an inventory, you want to ask to the user if he/she wants to run a specific role, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this solution. I think you will like it. You can have your vars in another file and load them first.

```
---
- name: Run Specific Role
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    mymenu:
      - common
      - system
      - date
      - swap
      - users
    allowed_items:
      - "1"
      - "2"
      - "3"
      - "4"
      - "5"

  vars_prompt:
    - name: runmenu
      prompt: "Run\n1 - {{ mymenu[0] }}\n2 - {{ mymenu[1] }}\n3 - {{ mymenu[2] }}\n4 - {{ mymenu[3] }}\n5 - {{ mymenu[4] }}\n[Enter Values with Comma as Separator]"
      private: false

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Set Fact
      set_fact:
        menu{{ item  }}: "menu{{ item  }}"
      with_items: "{{ runmenu.split(',') }}"
      when: item in allowed_items

  roles:
  - role: common
    when: menu1 is defined
```

Comment: It works nicely, quite similar to my solution. Seems approx the same amount of copy-paste and editing as mine, so not that dynamic... I guess vars_prompt just can't be used within a role so it has to be done on the playbook level, and no loops and items to make it more elegant...

Comment: Yep, it’s a pity it has not that flexibility.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466675/ansible-to-conditionally-prompt-for-a-variable what I requested can't be done, and is so by design. So I set this as an answer. Both this and my example work.